# Diacritic insensitive results from Realm database query using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate, diacritics, foundation

I'm implementing a search field in my app where user can type a name of a product to filter items displayed in a view.

I've made a query into Realm database using NSPredicate and it looks like this:

```
let productResults = try ProductDAO.fetchObjects(predicate: NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[cd]%@", pattern))
```

Im using `[cd]` modifiers so results should be case and diacritic insensitive.

It looks like it works fine so when I type for example:

> brazowy

The result is:

> Cukier brązowy

But when I type word with `L` letter I couldn't find any products that contain `Ł` letter.
From input:

> "maslo"

I should be able to find products like:

> "Masło"

**But there is no results**, it seems like it's a problem with polish `Ł` letter. 
Does someone know if there any other solutions to get correct result or if I am using this the wrong way?

Comment: I'm very curious as to why `Ł` is being treated differently that other diacritics...

Comment: I did some testing and this seems to be a problem with the `diacriticInsensitive` option for `String` comparison in the `Foundation` framework, this is not specific to `Realm` or `NSPredicate`. Using `NSString.compare` with the `diacriticInsensitive` option yields the same result as your code.`NSString(string: "Maslo").compare("maslo", options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]).rawValue` returns 0 as expected, while `NSString(string: "Masło").compare("maslo", options: [.diacriticInsensitive, .caseInsensitive]).rawValue` is 1 meaning that the two strings aren't the same.

Comment: Realm uses Foundation's string-comparison functionality as part of its implementation of diacritic insensitive comparison (see here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/Realm/RLMQueryUtil.mm#L153), so it makes sense that a Foundation bug in this area would lead to Realm producing the same sort of incorrect comparison. Would you be willing to file a Radar?

Comment: [U+0141](http://www.charbase.com/0141-unicode-latin-capital-letter-l-with-stroke) and [U+0142](http://www.charbase.com/0142-unicode-latin-small-letter-l-with-stroke) have no Unicode decomposition.  I see no issue with Foundation here.  According to the Unicode standard, this isn't a diacritic.